# Unzipping zipped folders, ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unzip

Does anyone know how to unzip a folder that has been zipped so that just the files within the folder are returned instead of the folder itself.

Currently I am using this:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(<Zipped File Source>, <Unzipped File Destination>)
```

This works fine for files that have been zipped into one zip file, but for files within a folder that has been zipped, I just want the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Stewart_R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455494/stewart-r), for pointing me in the right direction on this one.

Just to reiterate, the "First Method" below works but not in the way I needed it to.

**First Method (VB):**

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(<Zipped File Source>, <Unzipped File Destination>)
```

As I previously mentioned in my question, using the above code unzips files that have been zipped together or a folder that contains files, but doing the latter will result in the folder-name with the files inside.  In order to get just the files try this **Second Method (VB):**

```
Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(<zip_file_path>)  // "<zip_file_path>" is the location of your zip file
    For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries 
        If entry.Name.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then   //  ".txt" is the extention that you're looking for
           entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(<unzip_to_path>, entry.Name))             //  "<unzip_to_path>" is the destination folder
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

**Note:**

"entry.Name" returns the actual filename with its extention i.e.;

```
"somefile.txt"
```

This is important due to the fact that unzipping using the "first method" returns;

```
"folder_name/somefile.txt"
```

This behavior can be duplicated using the "second method" if you replace;

```
"entry.Name"
```

with;

```
"entry.FullName"
```

**Final Note:**

If you have more than one extension that you are trying to match you may add an "or" (VB), or a || (C#) within the conditional:

```
VB:
   entry.Name.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) or
   entry.Name.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then

C#:
   entry.Name.EndsWith(".txt", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
   entry.Name.EndsWith(".jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

The same code unzips all files.

From here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

we have:

> Extracts all the files in the specified zip archive to a directory on
>   the file system.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but that is not what I am asking.

Comment: ? Then I'm afraid I don't understand the question. This does give you all the files within a folder that has been zipped

Comment: I want to unzip the folder and have all the files saved in whatever directory I specify.  As it is now it unzips the folder and saves the folder with all the files within that folder.  There is another application that needs to look in that directory and is expecting to see files not another directory.  To further elaborate, there may be times that someone zips a set of files together and uploads that zip and other times they may zip a folder that has the files and upload that instead.  This disrupts the directory location that the other application is accessing.

Comment: Gotcha. That comment cleared up what I misunderstood. You can iterate over all the files (and save them wherever you please) within a `ZipArchive` object. There is an example here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx